# MariaDB errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key

Всем привет! 
Никак не могу понять, почему при создании таблицы с внешним ключом ловлю ошибку.

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (int),
  username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE tasks (
  login VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  countOfTask INT NOT NULL,
  taskName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_desc`
  FOREIGN KEY (login) REFERENCES users (username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `test`.`tasks` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: foreign должен ссылаться на первичный ключ другой таблицы. Т.е. он может ссылаться только на поле id таблицы users

Comment: Переписал, та же ошибка. 

CREATE TABLE users (
 username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (int)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE tasks (
    login VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    countOfTask INT NOT NULL,
    taskName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `tasks_desc`
 FOREIGN KEY (login) REFERENCES users (username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_username ON users (username)`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, Akina!

Выкладываю правильный ответ.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (int),
  username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_username ON users (username);

CREATE TABLE tasks (
  login VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  countOfTask INT NOT NULL,
  taskName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_desc`
  FOREIGN KEY (login) REFERENCES users (username)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Как я понимаю, обязательно должна быть индексация.

Comment: Согласно документации https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/ и стандарту SQL, ссылка должна быть однозначной, т.е. либо на первичный либо на альтернативный ключ (PRIMARY KEY и UNIQUE соответственно)